# $set only when the field does not exists when using the array operator in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I need to set a default value to my documents but only when the field does not exists. My problem is that I am using an array operator.

My request is like this :

```
db.myCollection.updateMany({}, { $set: { 'foo.$[].bar.$[].test': 42 }})
```

`myCollection` contains the followings two documents:

```
{
    foo: [
        { bar: [{ a: 1 }, { a: 2, test: 18 }] },
        { bar: [{ a: 1, test: 20 }, { a: 2, test: 18 }] }
    ]
}

{
    foo: [
        { bar: [{ a: 1, test: 40 }, { a: 2, test: 18 }] },
        { bar: [{ a: 1, test: 20 }, { a: 2, test: 18 }] }
    ]
}
```

But if the property `test` exists, I don't want to overwrite it. So in my example, I only want to set the default value of one subelement (in the first document).

How can i change my request to do it?

Comment: Why `{"foo.bar.test": {$exists:false}}` filter doesn't work for you?

Comment: What is the behavior of `"foo.bar.test"` when `foo` and `bar` are arrays ? And since `bar` contains multiples values (some elements with `test`, some elements without `test`), what will happen ?

Comment: Makes sense. It wasn't clear from the description. It's why it's recommended to include an example of the document. You will need to employ [arrayFilters](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/index.html#update-nested-arrays-in-conjunction-with-identifier) as a third argument. First filter will match documents that have at least one foo.bar without test, and the 3rd filter will deal with individual subdocuments. I am sure people will be keen to answer with the actual query if they had a sample document to test it against.

Comment: I edited my question. I will check arrayFilters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [arrayFilters](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/index.html#update-nested-arrays-in-conjunction-with-identifier),

- create a variable `b` for `bar` is exists
- create a variable `t` for `test` is not exists

```
db.myCollection.updateMany(
    {},
    { $set: { 'foo.$[b].bar.$[t].test': 42 } },
    {
        arrayFilters: [
            { "b.bar": { $exists: true } },
            { "t.test": { $exists: false } }
        ]
    }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of having an alternative to [absolutely correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64034644/1110423) you can benefit from v4.2+ feature of using [aggregation in updates](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/). This update should do the same:

```
db.myCollection.updateMany({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      foo: {
        $map: {
          input: "$foo",
          as: "f",
          in: {
            $map: {
              input: "$$f.bar",
              as: "b",
              in: {
                $mergeObjects: [
                  {
                    test: 42
                  },
                  "$$b"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

It would be great if you can compare performance of both updates.